# Spam identifying issue during edits

Tags: bug, editor

So I was trying to edit the post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979645/how-to-use-swip-control-segment-in-swift/39980120#39980120) and when I submitted my edit, StackOverflow showed some unexpected behavior that I have not encountered before while editing.

It flagged my edit as possibly having spam in it, but I believe that this was some sort of "bug".

As you can see from the screenshot below, StackOverflow claimed that the phrase "I am havin" was an indication that my edit contained spam. I edited it multiple times to incorporate different phrasing, but with no avail. I used word like "What I am trying to accomplish", or "The problem I have is..." and the first portion of each of these phrases was continuously marked as spam.

> [image: Bug screenshot]

Since I noticed that it was always pointing out the first characters of the post, I decided to try and add a new line before the body text of the post. I submitted the edit with the exact same wording as before, but with this new line, and it worked. As you can see from the photo below, my edit is now visible to me after doing so:

> [image: Successful edit]

Can anyone provide any insight into why this might be happening? I did some quick research and I couldn't find anyone else on Meta talking about the same problem.

**EDIT:**

In order to investigate this more fully, I then tried to perform another edit (on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980476/ios-how-to-detect-network-change-when-app-is-in-background)), without a return before the body text, and no such error was shown. This seems to indicate that it was specific to the post, but why would this be?

Comment: you sure you were trying to edit the answer and not the question?

Comment: Just as with the main site, you're expected to do *significant* research before posting questions.  A [simple search for the keywords of your issue here on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=body+cannot+contain) shows multiple matches that should have resulted in not posting a duplicate.